# Subset x and y variables separately in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset

I have a dataframe, `df`, that looks like so:

```
group   ID    y1    y2
A       1     21    14
A       2     11    21
A       3     21    17
...
B       1     71    12
B       2     41    14
B       3     31    15
...
```

And would like to use `ggplot()` to plot variables in one group against variables in another. For example, `df$y1[df$group=="A"]` against `df$y2[df$group=="B"]`. I naively thought the code for plotting may be something like this, but it's obviously not correct:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = df$y1[df$group=="A"], y = df$y2[df$group=="B"])) + geom_point()
```

I know that if I wanted to subset the overall data, for example to plot only `group A`, I could do something like:

```
ggplot(subset(df, group=="A"), aes(x = y1, y = y2)) + geom_point()
```

I think I could solve this by reshaping my data so as to create variables `y1.A`, `y1.B`, `y2.A`, `y2.B` and so forth, but I have many variables and this seems like a long-winded approach.

Comment: Are you always comparing `y1` from one group against `y2` from another?

Comment: Do all the groups have the same number of observations. Are they "units" always in the same order in the data.frame for each group? you'll get different plots depending on which row of A you match up to which row of B. I think reshaping is going to be your best bet here.

Comment: Yes (I meant to include this in the question, I've updated it now), the variables are paired between groups, with pairs sharing the same ID number. Do you think `melt()` or `reshape2()` is probably the easiest way forward then?

Comment: No @DavidRobinson, I have dozens of `y` variables which I may compare with each other. I'm using `corrplot()` to show a summary plot of all pairwise correlations as there are so many, but would also like to `ggplot` a select few individually.